# Visual Studio Code: Change used CMake installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I have different CMake installations (Cygwin and Win) and I want to keep the Cygwin one in my PATH variable. From a Visual studio Code project I want to use the other CMake installation but it is always using the one inside the PATH variable.
Is there a way to give VS Code an absolute path to the CMake to be used?

Comment: Usage of CMake is controlled by the specific VSCode CMake extension that you use, refer to their docs

Answer (score 0):

AS I found out it can be set here:
[image]